# Regex Condition to replace a value in Notepad++/Javascript

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a huge json array file.But after each json object instead of comma(,).I have

```
/* 1 */      (i.e., /* indexno */).
```

This way I have around more than 100 object.

Can someone help me in Regex such that

```
   /* somenumber */ will be replaced with ,
```

Please help.Thanks!

Comment: Find `/\* \d+ \*/` and replace with `,` ... but it isn't clear how extensive you want the replacement to be.  You should show us a few lines of sample input here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I believe he wants to replace the comment with `,`, so I think `\/\* \d+ \*\/` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ you can do the following steps -> Ctrl + H then go to Regular Expression option and tick it. In Find what paste this code and just put what you want in Replace with

**With End Line**

```
\/\*\s\d+\s\*\/$
```

**Without End Line**

```
\/\*\s\d+\s\*\/
```

*Another easy way you can always use in such cases is to hold Shift + Win button and drag with the keyboard up/ down arrows to make batch select :)*

Comment: Slashes don't need to be escaped.